# Access SharePoint 2010 List remotely from a WPF Client using Lists Web Service

Tags: wpf, web-services, sharepoint, authentication

I recently developed a WPF client application from my local machine to access a SharePoint 2010 List from a remote SharePoint Server. I thought that I should use custom NetworkCredentials object to authenticate my request. But just using CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials was enough to access the remote SharePoint server and get all list items and update list items as well.

I wonder how this would be possible because the SharePoint server doesn't know me. By just using CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials did the magic. So what about the security of my SharePoint Data? Please explain me this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials is set to the current Domain user running the WPF client application.

Sharepoint permissions are still checked, so the only way the WPF application can access the data on sharepoint is if the current user has access rights on that particular content.